# How do I know how many indexes I need for ELK?

Tags: docker, filebeat, elk

I'm new here, so I'm not quite sure how to calculate the load for indexes
I have 45 containers. The containers are categorized into core-..., modules-..., and infrastructure. I need to collect container logs from each category.
I understand that I also need to create 3 indexes for each category? Or 45 containers? I don't really understand their functionality. I was told that it is analogous to a list.
I need all the docker logs of a container to be stored for one day only. I have all containers running through docker-compose.
Is the more indexes the better? I don't understand it very well.

Comment: I would also add an Elasticsearch tag here. The number depends on several factors